# Using Google Analytics for software tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Could I use Google Analytics (Free Edition) for tracking statistics of my software? Or should I pay for using this service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can send data to Google Analytics using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference)(beta). From your software make an HTTP POST or GET to the below url:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect
```

Refer [Parameter Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) link for the list of parameters you can send via Measurement Protocol.

Sample code in Java:

```
HttpClientWrapper http = new HttpClientWrapper();
HttpParameter[] params = new HttpParameter[8];
params[0] = new HttpParameter("v", "1");
params[1] = new HttpParameter("tid", "UA-XXXX");
params[2] = new HttpParameter("cid", clientId);
params[3] = new HttpParameter("t", "appview");//hit type
params[4] = new HttpParameter("an", app);
params[5] = new HttpParameter("av", version);                       
params[6] = new HttpParameter("cn", campaignName);
params[7] = new HttpParameter("cd", screen);

HttpResponse response = http.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect",
 params);
System.out.println("Response:" + response.asString());
```

Comment: Can I send pure GET request like described below?
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmp=Login+Page&utmac=UA-44162335-1&utmwv=5.2.2&utmcc=__utma%3D1.8841297105.1.1.1.1%3B&utmn=7636478430

Comment: Measurement protocol supports GET request on the same end point:  http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?payload_data&z=123456